# How to verify user login from file in C++?

Tags: c++, authentication

i am trying to create a simple program which asks for user registration and saves the records to the file and if the user is already registered he can then login through his username and password. 
But the problem is how do i verify that whether username and password are already present in records.txt file? and are they correct? so user can login.
I have tried many ways but i cant get it working. I am a university student.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string uName, pass, name, email, gender;
string logname, logpass;
string valname, valpass;
int phone;
ofstream output;
output.open("record.txt");
cout<<"Enter username: "<<endl;
cin>>uName;
cout<<"Enter password: "<<endl;
cin>>pass;
cout<<"Enter name: "<<endl;
cin>>name;
cout<<"Enter email: "<<endl;
cin>>email;
cout<<"Enter gender: "<<endl;
cin>>gender;
cout<<"Enter phone number: "<<endl;
cin>>phone;

output<<uName<<" "<<pass<<" "<<name<<" "<<email<<" "<<gender<<" "<<phone<<endl;
output.close();
cout<<"Registration complete!"<<endl;


//  login
ifstream input("record.txt");

cout<<"Enter username:"<<endl;
cin>>logname;
cout<<"Enter password:"<<endl;
cin>>logpass;

if((input>>uName)==logname && (input>>pass)==logpass) { 
//input>>uName trying to get to the file and 
//read the already entered uName and match with the current entered name by user, same with pass
    cout>>"Login successful"<<endl;
}
else {
    cout<<"Login failed!"<<endl;
}

input.close();
cout<<"Done!"<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

EDIT:
I am having trouble logging in.
Here is the compile log:

https://pastebin.com/FmWizEtr

word limit exceeding.

EDIT 2: 
here is my record.txt file if i remove my login code:

```
john666 qwertyui John john23@gmail.com Male 682739658
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT 3: THANKYOU so much its working heres the working code (changed a little bit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string uName, pass, name, email, gender;
    string logname, logpass;
    string valname, valpass;
    int phone;
    int choice;
    cout<<"Enter choice:"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Register\t\t2.Login"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;

    if (choice==1) {
        ofstream output;
        output.open("record.txt");
        cout<<"Enter username: "<<endl;
        cin>>uName;
        cout<<"Enter password: "<<endl;
        cin>>pass;
        cout<<"Enter name: "<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter email: "<<endl;
        cin>>email;
        cout<<"Enter gender: "<<endl;
        cin>>gender;
        cout<<"Enter phone number: "<<endl;
        cin>>phone;

        output<<uName<<" "<<pass<<" "<<name<<" "<<email<<" "<<gender<<" "<<phone<<endl;
        output.close();
        cout<<"Registration complete!"<<endl;

    }
    else if(choice==2){
        //  login
        ifstream input("record.txt");

        if(!input) {
            cout<<"Error creating file!";
        }

        cout<<"Enter username:"<<endl;
        cin>>logname;
        cout<<"Enter password:"<<endl;
        cin>>logpass;

        if (input >> uName && input >> pass &&     // check if reading was successfull
        uName == logname && pass == logpass) { //input??uName trying to get to the file and read the already entered uName and match with the current entered name by user, same with pass
            cout<<"Login successful"<<endl;


        }
        else {
            cout<<"Login failed!"<<endl;
        }

        input.close();
        cout<<"Done!"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Please enter a valid choice!"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;

   }
```

Comment: I guess the problem is, that you can't login? It's always helpful to include a detailed description of expected and actual output. If you have compiler errors (which is the case as I just found out) please also include them in the question.

Comment: How does your text file look?

Comment: i have updated with log, error and my txt file thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is this line

```
if((input>>uName)==logname && (input>>pass)==logpass)
```

where you mix up two design pattterns. As you can see in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) all overloads of `std::basic_istream::operator>>` return a `basic_istream &`.

This means that `input>>uName` returns a reference to `input`, which you can't compare to a `std::string`. The correct pattern would be the following:

```
if (input >> uName && input >> pass &&     // check if reading was successfull
    uName == logname && pass == logpass)   // check if the read data matches the input
```

---

The other problem is

```
cout>>"Login successful"<<endl;
```

which is just a typo and must be

```
cout<<"Login successful"<<endl;
```

---

As a last side note, you should always check if a stream was opened successfully:

```
    ifstream input("record.txt");

    if(!input) { /* error occurred while opening */ }
```